# Is the matrix form of the cross product related to bilinear forms.

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, cross-product

The cross product of two vectors $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ can be represented as a matrix product as follows, if $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)^{\top}$ then $\mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{y} =  [\mathbf{x}]_{\times}\mathbf{y}$ where:

\begin{equation*}
[\mathbf{x}]_{\times} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -x_3  & x_2 \\ 
 x_3& 0 & -x_1\\ 
 -x_2&x_1  &0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Further more any skew-symmetric matrix has an associated bilinear form, If $M_{ij}$ is a skew symmetric matrix, then $B =  \sum_{i, j} M_{ij} dx_i \otimes dx_j$ is a bilinear form satisfying $B(i, j) = -B(j, i)$.

As such I thought that the skew symmetry of $[\mathbf{x}]_{\times}$, results from a natural associated bilinear form. However, the cross product returns a vector, not a scalar, like a bilinear form should, at least as I have learnt. However, this is not a homework question, so there is no need to provide only hints.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for but one can define the cross product via the one form $x \mapsto \det \begin{bmatrix} x & u & v\end{bmatrix}$, and this one form can be written as $x \mapsto \langle x , c \rangle$ for some $c$ which we call $u \times v$.

Comment: could you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Of course. What needs clarification? Note that this is similar to the answer below, the connection is the 'triple product', that is, $\langle a, b \times c \rangle  = \det \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Nah, I get it. How can you represent a one-form using a matrix though? I always thought you represented them using row-vector fields.

Comment: I did not understand matrix elements. Can anyone please elaborate them .thankns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ you get the skew symmetric matrix $[x]_\times$. This matrix does correspond to a bilinear form. It corresponds to the bilinear form $$H:\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R} \ , \ (a,b)\mapsto a^T[x]_\times b=a^T\cdot(x\times b)$$I think you may be wondering why the matrix $[x]_\times$ is skew-symmetric? By definition $x\times y=-(y\times x)$ and so this bilinear form $H$ is skew symmetric. That is, $H(a,b)=-H(b,a)$. Hence the matrix representation of $H$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, I took so long. I went to South Africa for holidays and internet access is very expensive there. One more thing before, I accept your answer, could you prove that H is skew-symmetric? I'm finding trouble doing this, essentially because I don't know how to manipulate a scalar triple product, so as to rearrange the vectors involved.

Comment: $H$ is skew-symmetric because $[x]_x$ is. Since $H(a,b)$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, we have $H(a,b)^T=H(a,b)$. Hence $H(a,b)=a^T[x]_xb=(b^T[x]_xa)^T=-(b^T[x]_xa)^T=-(H(b,a))^T=-H(b,a)$

Comment: I probably shouldn't have proved $H$ was skew-symmetric using that $[x]_x$ was since that was your question. You can see $H$ is skew symmetric because $H(a,b)=a^T\cdot(x\times b)=(x\times b)a$ since the dot product of two vectors $u,v$ is equal to $uv^T$. Lastly $(x\times b)a=-(b\times x)a=-(b^T\cdot(x\times a))=-H(b,a)$. Here I used that $u\cdot (v\times w)=(u\times v)\cdot w$.